# possible characters base64 url safe function

Tags: php, base64

What is the range of possible characters returned from this string?

```
function base64url_encode($data) 
{ 
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}
```

My guess is `[a-z0-9-_]`

Comment: base64 is case sensitive. so that should be a-zA-Z0-9-_

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The range of possible characters returned are:

- `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z`
- `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z`
- `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`
- `-` (*minus*) and `_` (*underscore*)

In your regex-style, that would be `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`.

Comment: sorry to revive an old post.. but it's worth mentioning that `base64encode` likes to add `=` to the end of some string as "padding" to keep string length a modulo 4 number. See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4492448/648350

Comment: @haxxxton and those `=` are being explicitly `rtrim`-ed in the question's `base64url_encode` function.

Comment: @salathe agreed, i just thought it was worth mentioning what the default behaviour for `base64encode` was, as when i was searching for what it's possible values were, this was one of the first posts that came up :)

Comment: there is also an '=' equal sign just like this string "RElMR19OZXdzX0NlbnRyYWxfMjAxMTExMThfZGE2NTU0NjI0Zi5qcGc=.jpg"

Comment: @FrederickG.Sandalo check the original question, the equals sign (=) is getting (r)trimmed.

Comment: ahhh yeah, I didnt notice the rtrim() function there

Answer (score 48):

Base64 encoded strings may contain the characters `a-z A-Z 0-9 + / =`.

You're removing the right-padding `=` and replacing `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`.

So in your case, the possible characters are `a-z A-Z 0-9 - _`

[More Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications)