# How to securely share a link to others - Laravel 5

Tags: php, security, laravel, hyperlink, laravel-5

Hi am making a Call Recording System, basically, there's admin and user. Admin will upload a call recording file which is stored in the file system. Then the admin will assign that a user a call recording which the user can see.

So in my database I have

```
RecordingsTable
->id
->Name
->Path
->FileName
```

then my Designation table which where I store the assigned call recording to a user.

```
DesignationTable
->id
->User_id
->Recording_id
```

I already make the function which the user can only see and play the recording assigned to him/her. My problem now is the user could also share that recording to someone else. I already done that, what I do is loading the the assigned recording to the user, and in his/her dashboard there's a public link for the video, say

`<a href="http://localhost/callrec/public/recording/{!! $value->recordID !!}">See Public Link</a>`

as you can see I'm using Blade Template. As you can that

`$value->recordID` is my recording ID which is a resource, so let's say that link directed to

```
http://localhost/callrec/public/recording/1
```

Then that link is public and the user can share it. But there's a risk, when he/she shared this that `id` from the link can be altered, let's say `http://localhost/callrec/public/recording/4` and if that `id` is existing it can be accessed which is supposed to be not coz the user only shared the `id = 1` . How to approach problems like this? Any ideas and suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Why not generate a hash value for the ID, with a custom salt value.

Comment: This would work, but remember that hash is a irreversible operation, so you will need to store the hash in your database together with the recording.

Comment: A permission based access would be the way to go. Disable non-authenticated access to the file

Comment: @AlexTartan if I would do that then that means each person that the user shared the link needs to be registred or logged in? Or needs to be assigned a file as well?

Comment: it is possible to do it, there is a similar solution to protect images only for logged users, see if you can get inspiration how to do it, if you get stuck, let me know I find you a solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456

Comment: @alexTartan, maytham: Please read the question. The OP wants to make the links shareable for public, just wants to prevent messing with the links so that other recordings cannot be viewed.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo OK As I understand only logged on users should access the links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ID in the URL, then as you noticed it's easy to guess other possible IDs, change the URL and access other recordings. So what you need to do is to share links containing a value that users won't be able to guess. One example would be a hash of the recording ID using some secret value as a hash - e.g. your **APP_KEY** value.

What you need to do is:

1. Add a string **hash** column to your recording table
2. When recording is created, calculate the hash and save it with the recording:

   ```
   $recording = Recording::create($attributes);
   $recording->hash = base64_encode(Hash::make
                          ($recording->recordID . Config::get('APP_KEY')));
   $recording->save();
   ```
3. Use that hash in the URLs

   ```
   <a href="http://localhost/callrec/public/recording/{!! $value->hash!!}">
      See Public Link
   </a>
   ```

This way your links will be publicly available, but guessing a hash of another recording will be more or less as hard as guessing passwords in your application as the same logic is applied. Just make sure you keep your **APP_KEY** safe.

Comment: Hi this is a very good idea, however, I will have problems with the URL if I use hash, say for example my hash is $2y$10$FpDtUyndvT6EiaWLPbYP2uEHDkIQrFz0uvtPPpQ81cKQ/v9ta6o0e then it will be on the url like http://localhost/callrec/public/recording/$2y$10$FpDtUyndvT6EiaWLPbYP2uEHDkIQrFz0uvtPPpQ81cKQ/v9ta6o0 the problem is that hash might have a forward slash / which will cause me a 404 error

Comment: Sorry, forgot about base64_encode :) I update the answer

Comment: You can see base64 characters here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102077/possible-characters-base64-url-safe-function - it should be safe for the URLs

Comment: Wow thank you so much. It works and the way I want it to be. You've helped me a lot. thank u so much :)

Comment: To whoever is downvoting the answer: please drop a comment, I'll be happy to learn what is wrong with this solution :)