# Generating AES 256 GCM secret using a given key in python

Tags: python, encryption, aes-gcm

I am trying to Implement AES encryption in python.
I am referring a java code sample in order to accomplish this.
In Java,  the 256 bit secret (using the given key) is generated using

`Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(GIVEN_KEY), "AES");`

I am trying to do the same in python using the following snippet

`secret = hashlib.sha256(GIVEN_KEY.encode()).digest()`

But the string encoded with python implementation is not being able to get decrypted.
Is the above snippets similar, or is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the Base64 decoded value of `GIVEN_KEY` is used as key, in Python, the SHA256 hash of `GIVEN_KEY`. Both are not the same.

The counterpart in Python would be something like:

```
import base64
...
secret = base64.b64decode(GIVEN_KEY.encode()) # by default UTF8 encoded
```

**EDIT**:
In the [linked code](https://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/help/in/EnterpriseAPIDocument.pdf) (p. 31) the key is [Base64url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) encoded *without* padding:

```
QOahfcdo98NLjYJuhP4-VKigx51NkUETsKlIu9uXZFY
```

which can be recognized by the character `-` and the length which is not divisible by 4.

This corresponds Base64url decoded to the byte sequence

```
40e6a17dc768f7c34b8d826e84fe3e54a8a0c79d4d914113b0a948bbdb976456
```

which represents a 32 bytes key (AES-256) and can be tested e.g. [here](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex).

In Python you can Base64url decode with [`urlsafe_b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64decode). However, a padded Base64url encoded value is expected, so that the padding has to be added first, e.g. with the `repad` method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9024884/9014097).

```
import base64

# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9024884/9014097
def repad(data):
    return data + "=" * (-len(data)%4)

GIVEN_KEY = 'QOahfcdo98NLjYJuhP4-VKigx51NkUETsKlIu9uXZFY'

secret = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(repad(GIVEN_KEY).encode()) 
print(secret.hex()) # 40e6a17dc768f7c34b8d826e84fe3e54a8a0c79d4d914113b0a948bbdb976456
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve the problem, it would be best to post both codes.

Comment: Base64 decoding won't solve it,  the char length of GIVEN_KEY  is not necessarily a multiple of 4.   the `SecretKeySpec` is doing some kind of key derivation.

Comment: `SecretKeySpec` creates a `SecretKey` based on the passed `byte[]`, it does not change the underlying data, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html). If its length does not match a valid AES key (16, 24, 32 bytes), an exception is thrown later (i.e. during encryption/decryption). Probably your problem is somewhere else. I can only recommend you to post both codes.

Comment: _...the char length of GIVEN_KEY is not necessarily a multiple of 4..._ With padding the length should actually be a multiple of 4. Maybe during the encoding of the key a Base64 variant is applied that doesn't pad. Apache's [`Base64.decodeBase64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64-java.lang.String-) decodes Base64 and Base64url encoded strings. While `Base64.encodeBase64String` pads, `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString` does not. Maybe you should check which Base64 variant was used to encode the key.

Comment: See the Sample Java code for AES encryption section in [this doc](https://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/help/in/EnterpriseAPIDocument.pdf)  (page number 31) ,  I am trying to recreate this in python.

Comment: The Java code indeed uses a Base64url encoded key without padding, which has to be decoded accordingly in the Python code, see the EDIT section in my answer.

Comment: That's some progress.  I tried this method.  Now I am no longer getting the key lengith issue.   But the remote service is still not able to decrypt the string I  am encrypting.  Let me share the python code as well for your reference.

Comment: @Hrishi - This question here is answered. Please ask a new question and post both codes in the question (and not just as links in comments). Thanks.