# How to remember login status in an iOS app with a Node.js backend

Tags: ios, session, authentication, remember-me

I'm making a social iOS app. In order to "remember" user's login status, what I did so far:

1. for the first time the user logs in/create a new account, the app saves his/her username and password in keychain, and next time when the app launches, in

   ```
   (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   // submit login
   ```

   }

   the app submits the username/password in keychain to login the user automatically;
2. In nodejs I set the session expiration time to be 2 hours.

Now suppose after the app launches and automatic login happens, if the app entered background for a long time(longer than 2 hours) and then switch back to foreground, is the user NO LONGER logged in?

If the login status is gone, how can I remain the login status? What I can think of is to add another automatic login logic in

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // submit login
}
```

But wouldn't that be too much data transmission involved?

Or maybe I can set a permanent session time on the server side? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to achieve this functionality is to generate a token key for mobile device which can be expire in a long time, you can keep it alive like for 30 days and only invalidate until user logout manually.

Comment: So in my understanding, you're refering to an access token? How may I generate that access token, is there an algorithm to generate it? I see OAuth might be able to do that, though I haven't go deep into it yet, is that so?

Comment: Yes, OAuth has this functionality to generate token, it will be on server side and client just need to store it and send to API as key param. Here is a function of java to generate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141292/oauth-2-0-generating-token-and-secret-token